# Remove file extension in reverse ISAPI Rewrite

Tags: regex, iis, isapi-rewrite

So I'm having trouble coming up with a good Regex pattern to remove a file extension from a url with Helicon ISAPI Rewrite. It needs to be able to match any type of extensions and remove it? It most be done in ISAPI do to a lack of.. shall we say control (causing possible case of programmers rage) on the app source. Any Ideas?

Thanks!

---

Example

Browser URL: www.derp.com/folder/file.aspx --> IIS Request URL: www.derp.com/folder/file

Browser URL: www.derp.com/img/cutepuppy.jpg --> IIS Request URL: www.derp.com/img/cutepuppy

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\..+$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]
```